# Strange issue with ASP.NET MVC3 client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am having an issue with ASP.NET MVC3 client side validation.

My view is based on a viewmodel I've created with the following fields as `Required`

```
public class AppointmentFeedbackViewModel_Validation
{

    [Required]
    public string AttendeeName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Notes must be filled in")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Appointment status must be filled in")]
    public int AppointmentStatusId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int StarId { get; set; }

}
```

Unfortunately, a completely unrelated field `SubStatusId` appears as required on submitting the form.

This drop down list is passed an empty `List` from the controller

```
new List<EF.ViewModels.OpportunityConnectTypeViewModel>();
```

and marked up as below

```
<div class="display-label-styled">
    Please select another reason for this outcome
</div>
<div class="display-field-styled">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubStatusId, new SelectList(ViewBag.SubStatus, "ID", "StatusName"))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubStatusId)
</div>
```

If anybody can shed any light on this for me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show the whole view? Is it strongly typed? To what class? We need to see what the model type is for the view? I suspect it doesn't match your validation model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is SubStatusId an int? Int's are implicitly required. If you want it to not be required, declare it as a nullable int:

public int? SubStatusId;